# Alphaleonis File.OpenRead() throws "The system cannot find the path specified." when pathlength>256

Tags: c#, filepath, system.drawing, system.io.file, pathtoolongexception

I have a problem opening images with pathlength > 256. I'm using Alphaleonis, which works for me copying and finding files but on

```
System.IO.FileStream file = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.OpenRead(item)
```

when the path has more than 256 characters there is an exception thrown ("The system cannot find the path specified."). Complete Method:

```
public static List<System.Drawing.Image> Find(string folderPath, string filenameOrPart)
        {
            List<System.Drawing.Image> imges = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();
            try
            {
                List<string> filesInFolder = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).ToList();
                List<string> filesFound = filesInFolder.Where(f => f.Replace(folderPath, "").Contains(filenameOrPart)).ToList();
                foreach (var item in filesFound)
                {
                    int pathLen = item.Length;
                    try
                    {
                        using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                        using (System.IO.FileStream file = Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.OpenRead(item))
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                            int read;
                            while ((read = file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length)) > 0)
                            {
                                ms.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                            }
                            imges.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //dont add pic
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //return empty list
            }
            return imges;
        }
```

It works for images where pathLen < 257 but goes into inner catch if path is longer. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Additional info: Images are on a Network drive

Edit2: Needed to update Alphaleonis and call the method as in accepted answer.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure with your scenario. But, to read details of files longer than 256 length, try Path.Combine(@"\?\", "your folder path")

I tried below code, folder length is longer than 300 and it worked

```
string path = "C:\\1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
        int filesCountOnShareDrive = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(@"\\?\", path))
                            .Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date).Count();
```

**Updated:**

I do not know why it is not working for you. But, below code works fine for me

```
public static List<System.Drawing.Image> Find(string folderPath, string filenameOrPart)
    {
        List<System.Drawing.Image> imges = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();
        try
        {
            List<string> filesInFolder = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).ToList();
            List<string> filesFound = filesInFolder.Where(f => f.Replace(folderPath, "").Contains(filenameOrPart)).ToList();
            foreach (var item in filesFound)
            {
                int pathLen = item.Length;
                try
                {
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    using (System.IO.FileStream file = File.OpenRead(item))
                    {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            ms.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                        }
                        imges.Add(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //dont add pic
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //return empty list
        }
        return imges;
    }
```

Calling part below

```
 string path = "C:\\1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
        Find(Path.Combine(@"\\?\", path), "Test");
```

Test image is placed inside the folder

Comment: Doesn`t change anything... Maybe it has to do with image being on a Network drive? (adding this info to original post too).

Comment: also getting filename/count works. The exception happens on 'code'System.IO.FileStream file =File.OpenRead(item)'code'

Comment: Iv'e copied your code and removed Alphaleonis.... "The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters." - maybe it doesn't work with Network directories?

Comment: Ok got it to work with updated Alphaleonis-version and your way to call the method. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @MMMagic glad it heped :-)